# AngularJS resolve before state loads

Tags: angularjs

So I am trying to build a theme swapper in my application. My HTML looks like this:

```
<link href="assets/css/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'default' || !settings.theme">
<link href="assets/css/themes/blue-hoki.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'blue-hoki'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/blue-steel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'blue-steel'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/green-haze.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'green-haze'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/purple-plum.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'purple-plum'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/purple-studio.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'purple-studio'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/red-intense.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'red-intense'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/red-sunglo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'red-sunglo'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/yellow-crusta.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'yellow-crusta'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/yellow-orange.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'yellow-orange'" />
```

As you can see from this, there is a default.css file that is loaded if there is no theme selected or if the selected theme is the default one.
I have a save page that allows the user to select a theme, that bit all works fine.

The problem I have is when I refresh the page or login, you see the default theme first before it loads the user's selected theme and then swaps to that.
The code I have to detect the users theme looks like this:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AccountService', 'CompanyService', function ($rootScope, $state, account, companyService) {

    // On state change
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {

        // Caused each state change to scroll to the top of the page
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

        // Get our user
        var user = account.current(); // This is set in our account service

        // If we have a user and the companyId has not been set
        if (user && user.authenticated && !$rootScope.settings) {

            // Get our company id
            var companyId = user.companyId;

            // Get our company
            companyService.get(companyId).then(function (response) {

                // Create our settings object
                var settings = {
                    theme: response.data.theme,
                    logo: response.data.logo
                };

                console.log(settings);

                // Add to our rootScope
                $rootScope.settings = settings;
            });
        }
    });
}])
```

Does anyone know how I can get the theme to load before the view is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state to which you transition once you have started your app then in the resolve of that state you need to call your service and get your theme data. you need to add .$promise to you call so the controller waits with loading until the data is fetched.

for more details check out this link http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/

```
//landingpage
<div ng-controller="startCtrl"></div>

//mainpage.html
<div ng-controller="MainPageController">
<link href="assets/css/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'default' || !settings.theme">
<link href="assets/css/themes/blue-hoki.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'blue-hoki'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/blue-steel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'blue-steel'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/green-haze.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'green-haze'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/purple-plum.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'purple-plum'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/purple-studio.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'purple-studio'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/red-intense.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'red-intense'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/red-sunglo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'red-sunglo'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/yellow-crusta.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'yellow-crusta'" />
<link href="assets/css/themes/yellow-orange.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.theme === 'yellow-orange'" />
</div>

//startctrl
    angular.module('myApp').controller('startCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
        var companyId = user.companyId;
       $state.go('mainState',{companyId: companyId});
    });

//mainctrl 
    angular.module('myApp').controller('MainPageController', function ($scope,company, $stateParams) {
            $scope.theme = company.theme;
    });

// your new state
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
        .config(function($stateProvider){
            $stateProvider.state('mainState', {
                url: 'main/:companyId',
                views: {
                    '@main': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/mainpage.html',
                        resolve: {
                            companyService: 'CompanyService',
                            company: function (companyService, $stateParams) {

                   //this is where the magic happens 
                   //$promise makes sure the controller 
                   //only loads when the promise is resolved

                                return  companyService.get($stateParams.companyId).$promise;
                            }
                        },
                        controller: 'MainPageController'
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```